# ERROR 1049 (42000): Unknown database 'psa' (PLESK)

Tags: ubuntu, plesk

I guess I did something really stupid, but any help or advice will be welcome.

Long story short: My server was full, so I couldn't login into Plesk and all my sites were down.

I tried to fix it with the repair tool kit, but I could not login, my credentials were rejected (I tried to use root & password, but it didn't work). Next thing I did was to try to reset Plesk admin's password using this command: **plesk bin admin --set-admin-password -passwd "new_password"**, but I got the following error: **DB query failed: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory**, so I read somewhere that I could free some space by deleting logs in **/var/log** and dumps in **/var/lib/psa/dumps/** …so I did. *HUGE MISTAKE, I GUESS*

Now, I can't access to Plesk, not even the repair tool kit, and every time I try to run **plesk login** command, I get this error: **DB query failed: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049] Unknown database 'psa' exit status 1**. Also, I get **ERROR 1049 (42000): Unknown database 'psa'** when I try to run **plesk db** command.

Please, tell me if there is a way I can get everything back on its right place without losing any of my websites data.

Additional info:

**Plesk Version:** Plesk Obsidian 18.0.41
**OS version:** Ubuntu 22.04

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: I saw the same question on the Plesk forum recently, probably that's you and probably it's already been solved by Plesk ticket support: https://talk.plesk.com/threads/error-1049-42000-unknown-database-psa.370941/